# Making a Jquery shuffle Gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery, shuffle

I'm trying to do a shuffle slideshow, like this [this site](http://www.tim-barber.com). It's a gallery with shuffle and fade but I have only this code:

```
<div class="slideshow">    
     <img src="http://davy0324.netne.net/dummys/dummy1.jpg">
     <img src="http://davy0324.netne.net/dummys/dummy2.jpg">
     <img src="http://davy0324.netne.net/dummys/dummy3.jpg">
     <img src="http://davy0324.netne.net/dummys/dummy4.jpg">
     <img src="http://davy0324.netne.net/dummys/dummy5.jpg">
</div>
```

Can you help me please? I've dealt with shuffles codes but they start with a button, but I don't want buttons, I want a automatic gallery, with repeated indefinitely like in the website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813064/jquery-image-slideshow-random-display-of-images

Comment: Easiest for that sort of thing could be the lightweight no-nonsense jQuery cycle plugin. Give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this (Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/))

```
$(function(){
    (function(){
        var imgs=$('.slideshow img');
        var i=0;
        function shuffle()
        {
            $(imgs[i]).fadeIn(2000, function(){
                i=(i < imgs.length-1) ? (i+1) : 0;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.slideshow img').fadeOut(2000);
                    shuffle();
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
        shuffle();
    })();
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6xMrc/14/).

**Update:** May be you want a random ordered image animation like [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6xMrc/15/).

Comment: jQuery and jQueryUI is not the same thing. Also why do you use nested functions? `$(function(){...})();` should work just fine.

Comment: I'm not using `jQuery UI`, anyway.

Comment: Yes!! perfect thanks! but the shuffle sequence that you showed it´s in order of images like dummy 1,2,3,4,5. ¿ Would it be possible that the sequence goes in random like dummy 5,4,2,3,1 for example? like this? http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/shuffle/demo.html

Comment: yes! thanks you very much Sheikh, one last thing, the sequence always starts with dummy image 1, can be the sequence start with any of the dummy images?

Comment: You shouldn't use StackOverflow if you that noob. Sorry, but learn a bit of JS first...